# Create folder hierarchy in zip - with gradle

Tags: groovy, zip, gradle

I'm trying to create a dist zip with gradle. I want to locate my jar at the root dir of the zip. and locating all my dependencies at lib folder . I didn't succeed to do so.

No matter what i tried only one folder is being created(I tried do create some folders).
And my artifact jar is included in this folder.

I will appreciate any help.

This is my task defintion :

```
task zip(type: Zip, overwrite:true) {
    from jar.outputs.files
    from configurations.runtime.collect{it}
    into ('lib')
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you need to do:

```
task zip( type: Zip, overwrite:true ) {
    from jar.outputs.files
    into( 'libs' ) {
        from configurations.runtime
    }    
}
```

As it shows in [the documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:archives)

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the `java-library-distribution` plugin.